# Scrapy Python Set up User Agent

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, screen-scraping, user-agent

I tried to override the user-agent of my crawlspider by adding an extra line to the project [configuration file](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#project-settings-module). Here is the code:

```
[settings]
default = myproject.settings
USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36"


[deploy]
#url = http://localhost:6800/
project = myproject
```

But when I run the crawler against my own web, I notice the spider did not pick up my customized user agent but the default one "Scrapy/0.18.2 (+http://scrapy.org)". 
Can any one explain what I have done wrong.

Note:

(1). It works when I tried to override the [user agent globally](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#global-overrides):

```
scrapy crawl myproject.com -o output.csv -t csv -s USER_AGENT="Mozilla...."
```

(2). When I remove the line "default = myproject.setting" from the configuration file, and run scrapy crawl myproject.com, it says "cannot find spider..", so I feel like the default setting should not be removed in this case.

Thanks a lot for the help in advance.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Move your USER_AGENT line to the `settings.py` file, and not in your `scrapy.cfg` file. `settings.py` should be at same level as `items.py` if you use `scrapy startproject` command, in your case  it should be something like `myproject/settings.py`

Comment: Here are the [UA strings](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en) to spoof Googlebot. Go forth and plunder.

Comment: Great. Solved my problem too.

Answer (score 5):

Just in case anyone lands here that manually controls the scrapy crawl. i.e. you do **not** use the scrapy crawl process from the shell...

```
$ scrapy crawl myproject
```

But insted you use `CrawlerProcess()` or `CrawlerRunner()`...

```
process = CrawlerProcess()
```

or

```
process = CrawlerRunner()
```

then the user agent, along with other settings, can be passed to the crawler in a dictionary of configuration variables.

Like this...

```
    process = CrawlerProcess(
            {
                'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)'
            }
    )
```

Comment: Do you also have an example how you can rotate user_agents? Just like using this: https://pypi.org/project/scrapy-user-agents/