# Scrapy authentication

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying use scrapy in one project. I have trouble bypassing the authentication system of https://text.westlaw.com/signon/default.wl?RS=ACCS10.10&VR=2.0&newdoor=true&sotype=mup .
To understand the issue, I did a simple request handler.

```
import cookielib, urllib2
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36'),]
url='https://text.westlaw.com/signon/default.wl?RS=ACCS10.10&VR=2.0&newdoor=true&sotype=mup'
r = opener.open(url)
f = open('code.html', 'wb')
f.write(r.read())
f.close()
```

The html code returned contains no form elements. May be someone know how to convince the server, that I am not a fake browser, so I can go on with authentication?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18920930/scrapy-python-set-up-user-agent

Comment: Would the problem come from
    r = opener.urlopen(url) instead of open ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `InitSpider`, which allows you to do some Post processing, such as logging in with a custom handler:

```
class CrawlpySpider(InitSpider):

    #...

    # Make sure to add the logout page to the denied list
    rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                allow_domains=(self.allowed_domains),
                unique=True,
                deny=('logout.php'),
            ),
            callback='parse',
            follow=True
        ),
    )


    def init_request(self):
        """This function is called before crawling starts."""

        # Do a login
        return Request(url="http://domain.tld/login.php", callback=self.login)


    def login(self, response):
        """Generate a login request."""

        return FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={
                "username": "admin",
                "password": "very-secure",
                "reguired-field": "my-value"
            },
            method="post",
            callback=self.check_login_response
        )

    def check_login_response(self, response):
        """Check the response returned by a login request to see if we are
        successfully logged in.
        """
        if "incorrect password" not in response.body:
            # Now the crawling can begin..
            logging.info('Login successful')
            return self.initialized()
        else:
            # Something went wrong, we couldn't log in, so nothing happens.
            logging.error('Unable to login')


    def parse(self, response):
        """Your stuff here"""
```

I have also just implemented a working example, which does exactly what you are trying to achieve. Have a look at it: https://github.com/cytopia/crawlpy