# Scrapy Shell - How to change USER_AGENT

Tags: python, shell, scrapy, agent

I have a fully functioning scrapy script to extract data from a website.  During setup, the target site banned me based on my USER_AGENT information.  I subsequently added a RotateUserAgentMiddleware to rotate the USER_AGENT randomly.  This works great.

However, now when I trying to use the scrapy shell to test xpath and css requests, I get a 403 error.  I'm sure this is because the USER_AGENT of the scrapy shell is defaulting to some value the target site has blacklisted.

Question:  is it possible to fetch a URL in the scrapy shell with a different USER_AGENT than the default?

fetch('http://www.test') [add something ?? to change USER_AGENT]

Thx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scrapy Python Set up User Agent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18920930/scrapy-python-set-up-user-agent)

Comment: different issue. I am able to change the USER_AGENT in settings.py no problem.  I'm trying to change the setting under scrapy shell: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`scrapy shell -s USER_AGENT='custom user agent' 'http://www.example.com'`

Comment: Do you know how to also add headers to scrapy shell? Thanks.

Comment: I got here because I was running the shell from outside the project directory and my settings file was being ignored. Once I changed into the project directory, the custom `USER_AGENT` setting worked properly, no need to pass any extra parameter to the `scrapy shell` command.

Answer (score 16):

Inside the scrapy shell, you can set the `User-Agent` in the `request` `header`.

```
url = 'http://www.example.com'
request = scrapy.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mybot'})
fetch(request)
```