# scrapy shell: I only see spider opened and then I get a time out for Zalando pages

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-shell

When I am in scrapy shell and I run:

```
fetch('https://www.google.nl')
```

Then I get a normal response:

```
2020-11-19 12:42:00 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-11-19 12:42:00 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.google.nl> (referer: None)
```

But when I do this for Zalando pages, for example:

```
fetch('https://www.zalando.de/nike-sportswear-pant-jogginghose-ni121a09o-c11.html')
```

Then I only see:

```
2020-11-19 12:46:06 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
```

And after a while I get a timeout.
Why is this not working for Zalando pages? Or: what should I change to make this work?

Comment: After getting the helpful answer, I realized this question + answers is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25429671/scrapy-shell-how-to-change-user-agent/40136365#40136365

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include a User Agent in your Request's headers, this worked fine for me:

```
from scrapy import Request
url='https://www.zalando.de/nike-sportswear-pant-jogginghose-ni121a09o-c11.html'
req = Request(url, headers={
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'
})
fetch(req)
```

Could be a anti-bot measure

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly :) I added still an Accept-Language to your headers: {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36', 'Accept-Language': 'de'}