# Scray shell URL returns 404 for endless scroll

Tags: python, scrapy

I am training on how to use scrapy shell in the command prompt and here's the URL
https://shopee.com.my/shop/145423/followers/?__classic__=1

For the google chrome developers (F12 pressed) and at the `Network` section, I have cleared everything and scoll down the website and got this link
https://shopee.com.my/shop/145423/followers/?offset=60&limit=20&offset_of_offset=0&_=1610787400133
The link is supposed to return some data but when trying

```
scrapy shell https://shopee.com.my/shop/145423/followers/?offset=60&limit=20&offset_of_offset=0&_=1610787400133
```

I got 404 as a response.
I think there's a popup that needs the user to click on the language and this is what makes the problem
How can such popup dealed with or skipped?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the URL in quotes, like `scrapy shell "the_url"`? Maybe the shell is interpreting `&limit=20` etc as setting environment variables?

Comment: I have tried your suugestion but the same problem. I have exported the `response.text` and noticed that part `<div class="label-select-language L24">Select Your Language</div>` so I think this is related to pop-up

Comment: It shouldn't be related to the pop-up. 404 means "there's no such page", while the pop-up comes _from the page you successfully loaded_, so it's an entirely different issue now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use User Agent . You can also use User Agent in [command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25429671/scrapy-shell-how-to-change-user-agent)

```
 headers={'User-Agent': 'Mybot'}
>>> r = scrapy.Request(url, headers=headers)
>>> fetch(r)
2021-01-16 16:53:11 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://shopee.com.my/shop/145423/followers/?offset=60&limit=20&offset_of_offset=0&_=1610787400133&__classic__=1> from <GET https://shopee.com.my/shop/145423/followers/?offset=60&limit=20&offset_of_offset=0&_=1610787400133>
2021-01-16 16:53:11 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://shopee.com.my/shop/145423/followers/?offset=60&limit=20&offset_of_offset=0&_=1610787400133&__classic__=1> (referer: None)
>>> response.status
200
>>>
```

Comment: Amazing. Can you explain what's `Mybot` used as header user-agent?

Comment: I tried such a line `response.css('li.clickable_area::text').getall()` but all what I got is only line breaks althrough there is `response.text` and the data is there.!!

Comment: User Agent can be firefox, chrome , details https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent .  response.css('li.clickable_area a::text').getall()
. Hope its help you.

Comment: That's great. As for the line `response.css('li.clickable_area a::text').getall()`, it works but I got a lot of empty results and also each name in the results are twice. How can this be achieved to get the names on the URL?

Comment: as a list response.css('li.clickable_area a::attr("href")').getall()
or for the single link use get() only

Comment: That's wonderful but I got each name three times.`['/empirefitnesssolution',
 '/empirefitnesssolution',
 '/empirefitnesssolution',
 '/nahyeock',
 '/nahyeock',
 '/nahyeock',`

Comment: I think you need to select proper css selector or use filter

Comment: for i in response.css('li.clickable_area'):
...     print(i.css('a::attr("href")').get())

Comment: Amazing. Thank you very much. Last point, why I got slash at the start of the string?

Comment: Because this is a part of url. you can join it with main url using response.urljoin()         for i in response.css('li.clickable_area'):
...     part =i.css('a::attr("href")').get()
...     response.urljoin(part)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227437/discussion-between-samsul-islam-and-yasserkhalil).