# Scrapy Only Returns Empty Arrays

Tags: web-scraping, terminal, scrapy

So I start my **scrapy** shell with

```
scrapy shell 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=tomatoes&ref=nb_sb_noss_1'
```

And I am trying to scrape the title of the products so I enter

```
response.xpath('//span[@class="a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal"]').getall()
```

and get: `[]`

And when I tried it in CSS with

```
response.css("span.a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal").getall()
```

I still get: `[]`

I don't understand why it isn't finding the element even though I am copying and pasting the tags and classes from the site.

I have also tried just writing **a-size-base-plus** for the classes in XPath and CSS but I still get nothing

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the spaces between the classes with dots if you want to match multiple classes on elements:

```
response.css("span.a-size-base-plus.a-color-base.a-text-normal").getall()
```

instead of:

```
response.css("span.a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal").getall()
```

Your selector with spaces says something like: Give me all `a-text-normal` elements inside `a-color-base` elements inside `span` elements with a class of `a-size-base-plus`. This is of course not what you want.

I've also had to set a user agent to get the correct results. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25438234/9098350) on how to set the user agent using scrapy shell.