# Can Scrapy be used with the Chrome Browser?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, scrapy

I need to scrape a web page that is a javascript-rendered AngularJS app. The developers of the site detect Safari/Firefox in private browsing mode and disallow it to be used, and therefore scraped. The page works with Safari/Firefox when you are not in private mode.

The interesting thing is that no such warning is given when using Chrome whether in private mode or not. I was using Scrapy+Selenium, but I was really hoping to use ScrapyJS/Splash for this project. However, it looks like the Scrapy/Splash combination suffers from the website's private browsing wall.

Is it possible to tell Scrapy to use Chrome? I know Selenium has quite a few drivers, and it is pretty well documented on how to use each, but I can't find any info on if Scrapy has support for other browsers or if someone else has already done this. Google/SO searches haven't illuminated this at all for me either.

Comment: Have you tried changing the user agent? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18920930/scrapy-python-set-up-user-agent

Comment: Yes, I tried this in the Scrapy `settings.py` file and it didn't seem to have an effect. I tried a few known Chrome/Firefox/Safari agents as well as some "Scrapy be a good citizen" user agents.

Comment: Have you tried using selenium's `chrome driver` ?

Comment: Sorry if I am wrong, but from my limited experience with Scrapy over an year ago, as far as I know, differently from Selenium, it doesn't really use the backend of any browser. It just sends HTTP requests using requests/twisted so the idea of "using browser X with Scrapy" doesn't seem to make much sense. I guess your best shot is trying Selenium.

Comment: @Randy, starting from Splash 2.0, you can disable private mode at startup or runtime. See https://splash.readthedocs.org/en/stable/changes.html#id4 _"it is now possible to turn Private mode OFF at startup using command-line option or at runtime using splash.private_mode_enabled attribute;"_

Comment: @Rahul - yes, I have tried that and it works, but I would like to use a Scrapy/Splash combination instead of Scrapy/Selenium.

Comment: @paultrmbrth - Thanks! I will check that out.

Comment: @paultrmbrth, if you want to add your comment as an answer, I tried it out and it works just as I hoped.

Comment: @Randy, done. Thx for the feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Starting from Splash 2.0](http://splash.readthedocs.org/en/stable/changes.html), you can disable Private mode (which is "on" by default).

There are two ways to go about it:

- at startup, with the --disable-private-mode argument, e.g., if you're using Docker:

  ```
  $ sudo docker run -p 5023:5023 -p 8050:8050 -p 8051:8051 scrapinghub/splash --disable-private-mode
  ```
- at runtime when using the `/execute` endpoint and setting [`splash.private_mode_enabled=false`](https://splash.readthedocs.org/en/stable/scripting-ref.html#splash-private-mode-enabled)

Also, take note of the effect of disabling private mode:

> Note that if you disable private mode browsing data such as cookies or items kept in local storage may persist between requests.