# Empty .json File in Scrapy

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy

I've written this very short spider to go to a U.S. News link and take the names of the colleges listed there.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import scrapy

class CollegesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "colleges"
    start_urls = [
        'http://colleges.usnews.rankingsandreviews.com/best-colleges/rankings/national-universities?_mode=list&acceptance-rate-max=20'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for school in response.css('div.items'):
            yield {
                'name': school.xpath('//*[@id="view-1c4ddd8a-8b04-4c93-8b68-9b7b4e5d8969"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/h3/a').extract_first(),
            }
```

However, when I run this spider and ask for the names to be stored in a file named schools.json, the file comes out blank. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you see items yielded in terminal/CLI?

Comment: @Umair what do you mean? My terminal output showed no errors.

Comment: @Umair I did get this though "HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed"

Comment: @ch1maera yeah I replicated that. My intuition is the auto stop robot. You need to code in some hearders and pretend tobe a browser

Comment: @Bobby so basically this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18920930/scrapy-python-set-up-user-agent ?

Comment: @ch1maera yes! I just tested it out using the lighter module request. It worked. It should work like a charm after you set up the header. See answer below

Comment: @Bobby Got it! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! It is because the robot detection.

Encode

```
>>> r = requests.get('http://colleges.usnews.rankingsandreviews.com/best-colleges/rankings/national-universities?_mode=list&acceptance-rate-max=20', headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36'})
>>> r.status_code
200
```

Then you will have all the content you need. Do whatever parsing or extraction you need. The procedure to encode a header should be very similar in Scrapy.

[scrapy doc for request with headers](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html)

User agent for Chrome

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 0):

I am on my mobile so don't remember exact variable name, but it should be robots_follow

Set it to False

Answer (score 0):

The page you're referring to as start url doesn't contain any element with id `view-1c4ddd8a-8b04-4c93-8b68-9b7b4e5d8969`- it looks like quite unique and doesn't seem to be the good choice for pretty universal XPath expression. I'd recommend to use something like `school.xpath('.//div[@data-view="colleges-search-results-card"]//h3/a/text()').extract()`

Comment: I tried that but I'm still getting "HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed"